# WP7 error when collapse lazy listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, lazy-loading, visibility

I'm using the very popular LazyListBox from [Peter Torr](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/10/12/procrastination-ftw-lazylistbox-should-improve-your-scrolling-performance-and-responsiveness.aspx). It works fine until I set its `Visibility` to **Collapsed**

```
<lazy:LazyListBox Visibility="Collapsed"> // cause error
    <lazy:LazyListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </lazy:LazyListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <lazy:LazyListBox.LoadedItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"></TextBlock>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </lazy:LazyListBox.LoadedItemTemplate>
</lazy:LazyListBox>
```

In Visual Studio designer I receive

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at LazyListBox.LazyListBox.ComputeVisibleItems() in D:\VSProjects\LazyListBoxProject\LazyListBox.cs:line 428
```

and the app crash when I run it

However, when I collapse it in code, it works just fine.

How to fix this? Set its `Visibility` in code does not suit my requirement

Comment: After setting it to collapsed, in your CS file you may be trying to set its content. In your code behind, make it to visible before setting its content !!

Comment: @nkchandra when I set it to collapsed, the designer show error. In my code, I do set it to visible before setting its ItemsSource